# Theme iteration with register_theme_directory in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, git, wordpress-theming

I'll try to make this a summarized as possible. But basically, I'm working on getting a parent and child WordPress theme to be activated from a git repo.

When cloning the git repo, it will put it into a subdirectory, which is fine.

So far I can access the parent and child theme correctly using `register_theme_directory` in the `wp-config.php` file like so:

```
register_theme_directory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/themes/repodir/parentTheme');
```

But when I go into the settings to activate either the parent theme or the child theme, I see this:

[image]

The current directory structure for the repo is like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|                                      |
| +-+wp-content                        |
|   |                                  |
|   +-+themes                          |
|     |                                |
|     +-+repodir                       |
|       |                              |
|       +-+parentTheme                 |
|       | |                            |
|       | +-+library                   |
|       | |                            |
|       | +-+styles                    |
|       | |                            |
|       | +-+scripts                   |
|       | |                            |
|       | +-+images                    |
|       | |                            |
|       | +-+modules                   |
|       |                              |
|       +-+childTheme                  |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

And for fun when I try to live preview any of the other Theme Parent(s) that are in there, I'll get an error saying something like:
`The theme directory "scripts/.." does not exist.`

or

`The theme directory "styles/.." does not exist.`

Which leads me to believe that it's picking up on the sub directories within my parent theme as possible WordPress theme directories?

I guess I'm not sure how to get it so that it only shows the two parent and child themes? Overall, I can activate the child theme and everything *appears* to be ok. So, I'm not sure why it's picking up on all of those directories as themes and is there anything that I can do to avoid it?

Here's the info that I have in the parent theme `style.css` since the main styles for the theme are in the `styles` folder:

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme Parent
Theme URI: http://www.urldomains.com
Description:  Theme Modules
Author: Me
Author URI: http://www.urldomains.com
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Not sure if I need to add anything in there as well?